# phpDocumentor produces invalid filenames

Tags: php, phpdoc

All links in produced documentation are like: `docs/classes/db_Foo/Bar.html`. The actual filenames do not contain any `db_` prefix, so the whole documentation points to just 404 pages.

Why are links generated with `db_` prefix but filenames not?

I have tried the latest tag v2 alpha2 from GitHub without luck.

The command I use:

```
php ..\phpDocumentor\bin\phpdoc.php -d src/Foo -t docs --ignore "*map*,*om*" --ignore-symlinks --template responsive
```

Comment: It's been years since PHPDocumentor was last updated and it looks like for all intents and purposes the project is dead.  Have you considered a more modern alternative, like DocBlox, Doxygen or ApiGen?

Comment: @GordonM:  DocBlox has merged to become phpDocumentor2.

Comment: DocBlox is phpDocumentor2, just a prototype name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours, I did search-and-replace for the `responsive` template and replaced all occurrences of `db_` and now the links work.

Comment: are you using some 1.x version of phpDocumentor with that "responsive" template from github?  If so, be advised that the template is only made for use with phpDocumentor versions 2.x.  If you are using 2.x, then this would indicate a bug.